# ArrayList index out of bounds

Tags: java, arraylist

Why `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` is raised in this example, if the size of ArrayList has been predefined? How to solve this problem?

```
int size = 2:
ArrayList<Integer[]> nums = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(size);
Integer[] value1 = {1,2,3};
Integer[] value2 = {1,2};
nums.add(1,value1); // java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
nums.add(0,value2);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot put an item in an ArrayList before the other one is set. If you want to do it you'll have to assign null values to the item on place 0 first.

It will work if you do:

```
int size = 2:
ArrayList<Integer[]> nums = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(size);
Integer[] value1 = {1,2,3};
Integer[] value2 = {1,2};
nums.add(0, null);
nums.add(1,value1);
nums.set(0,value2);
```

edit/ Replaced add by set to replace the null object

Comment: To be more clear, it's really that you can't insert an item at an index that doesn't yet exist.

Comment: Not to second guess the wisdom here, but doesn't the 3rd add() in the above solution *shift* the contents, such that value1 is now at index 2, not 1? The doc on add() with an index indicates so. I believe the array contents after this would be {value2,null,value1}.

Comment: The exception to the index rule is the index after the last index. It doesn't exist but you can add an element there to grow your list.

Answer (score 9):

The argument to the `ArrayList` constructor isn't the size of the list, as your code is assuming; it's the *capacity* of the underlying storage used by the data structure.

The capacity will grow as required as you add elements to the list. The only reason to specify the initial capacity in the constructor is to pre-allocate a larger capacity if you know you're going to be adding lots of elements. This means that the underlying array doesn't havwe to be resized too often as you add them.

Regardless of what value you specify in the `ArrayList` constructor, the *size* of the list is governed solely by what you put into it, so you can't fetch the item with `index` of 1 until you've added at least 2 elements.

Answer (score 3):

At the time that you `add()` to the `ArrayList`, the length of the list is 0. You cannot add past the current end of the `List`.

I would suggest doing:

```
nums.add(value2);
nums.add(value1);
```

To get the order you appear to want here.

Comment: It won't work for my case, because I might need to add a certain element at position 5, the next at position 2, the next at position 7, etc.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos - It's sounding like you don't really want an ArrayList, at least not initially. It may be better to start with an plain array of certain size, do all your inserts by index so you don't have to play funny games with the ArrayList, THEN put the Array into an ArrayList. Also, be aware that add() at an index causes a shift in the existing contents of the array. Adding at position 5, then position 2 changes what you inserted at 5 to now be at 6.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int)

What you specify it's the initial capacity, that's just the initial size that the internal array has and that is increased automatically if need be. **It has nothing to do with item position**, hence your error. By the way, the default capacity for ArrayLists is 10, so you are actually making it smaller than default.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29), When you write

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> nums = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(size);
```

You're not defining the **size** of *nums*, you're defining the **initial capacity** - in this sense, ArrayLists aren't like built-in arrays (*value1* and *value2* in your code).

You can try it yourself: print the size of *nums* after each line (code cleaned up to prevent the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
int size = 2:
ArrayList<Integer[]> nums = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(size);
Integer[] value1 = {1,2,3};
Integer[] value2 = {1,2};
System.out.println(nums.size());
nums.add(value2);
System.out.println(nums.size());
nums.add(value1);
System.out.println(nums.size());
```

This will print:

```
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you want to have, you have to write

```
nums.add(0, value1);
nums.add(0, value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the results you expect I would recommend to use base typed arrays like

```
Integer[][] nums = new Integer[size][];
```

and then

```
Integer[] value1 = {1,2,3};
Integer[] value2 = {1,2};
nums[1] = value1; 
nums[0] = value2;
```

If you still need an ArrayList just use

```
new ArrayList<Integer[]>(Arrays.asList(nums));
```