# Array index out of bounds: 30 (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, exception, bounds

I am writing a program to print out a user inputed integer into binary form.
When I run it and input, say the number 5, it crashes and gives me the error:
     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 30
    at PrintBinaryDigitsFixed.main(PrintBinaryDigitsFixed.java:27) 
i.e the line "digits[counter] = number % 2;"

Why am I getting an out of bounds exception? It should assign the remainder to the first element then move on to the second shouldn't it?

I feel like I'm making a glaringly obvious mistake but I can't tell what it is

```
 final int MIN = 0;
    final int MAX = (int) (Math.pow(2, 30) - 1);
    int[] digits = new int[30];                 //array to hold the digits

    int number = readInput
        ("Enter an integer from " + MIN + " to " + MAX, MIN, MAX);
    int counter = 0;
    int modNumber = 2;



    while(modNumber / 2 != 0)
    {
        digits[counter] = number % 2;
        modNumber = number / 2;
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.print(number + " in binary form is ");
    listBackwardsFrom(digits, counter);
```

Thanks

Comment: If `number = 5`, `number/2` returns `2` and hence `modNumber` is never equals to 0.

Comment: BTW, you may want to use bit masks and shift operators instead of mod and division. Will be way faster and cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've never heard of those so I'll have a look. They sound like something to do with cryptography?

Comment: and Thank you ZouZou too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArrayList index out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729786/arraylist-index-out-of-bounds)

Answer (score 4):

You never change `number` in your loop, and you assign `modNumber = number / 2` in the loop, so from the second iteration onward `modNumber` is a constant (for most of the first iteration it's `2`, but then you assign `number / 2` to it); if you reach that point at all, you'll stay there. So the loop continues until `counter` reaches `30`, at which point `digits[counter]` throws the exception.

Comment: Thanks! You can imagine my inward groan when I realised that I completely missed that