# Error array index out of bounds in some code

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

There is an array index out of bounds exception in my recursive function. Can someone try to point out to me why that is the case?
This line: return minChange(a, IntegerList); is having the array index out of bounds exception as well as most likely this line:

return minimumValue(1 + minChange(a - d, integerList), minChange(a, updatedList));

```
    /* Function minChange: Minimum Change
    Pseudo-code:
    minChange(0, ds)      = 0
    minChange(a, [])      = Failure
    minChange(a, d :: ds) = minChange(a,ds)                     if d > a
    minChange(a, d :: ds) = min(1 ++ minChange(a - d, d :: ds)  otherwise
     */
    public int minChange(int a, List<Integer> integerList) {

        //int minimumResult = 0;
        int indexNumber = 0;

        int d = integerList.get(indexNumber); (line 246)

        if(a == 0) {
            // If a is 0 return 0
            return 0;

        } else if(integerList.isEmpty()) {
            return -1;

        } else if(d > a) {

            integerList.remove(indexNumber); // Remove first element from list

            // Recursive call to minChange
            return minChange(a, integerList); (line 261)

        } else {
            // Create updatedList and remove first element
            List<Integer> updatedList = integerList;
            updatedList.remove(indexNumber);
            indexNumber++;

            return minimumValue(1 + minChange(a - d, integerList), minChange(a, updatedList)); (line 269)

        }


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out-of-bounds for length 0
at AlgorithmsSetZero.minChange(AlgorithmsSetZero.java:246)
    at AlgorithmsSetZero.minChange(AlgorithmsSetZero.java:261)
    at AlgorithmsSetZero.minChange(AlgorithmsSetZero.java:261)
    at AlgorithmsSetZero.minChange(AlgorithmsSetZero.java:261)
    at AlgorithmsSetZero.minChange(AlgorithmsSetZero.java:261)
    at AlgorithmsSetZero.minChange(AlgorithmsSetZero.java:261)
    at AlgorithmsSetZero.minChange(AlgorithmsSetZero.java:261)
    at AlgorithmsSetZero.minChange(AlgorithmsSetZero.java:261)
    at AlgorithmsSetZero.minChange(AlgorithmsSetZero.java:269)
    at AlgorithmsSetZero.minChange(AlgorithmsSetZero.java:269)
    at AlgorithmsSetZero.minChange(AlgorithmsSetZero.java:269)
```

How can I fix this array index out of bounds exception. It seems one line needs to be fixed. If so how can I fix this error? What are some ways?

Comment: Can you include the whole stack trace?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The whole paragraph that compiler throws on error. It has line numbers that tell you what caused the error.  Anyways I think your line `int d = integerList.get(indexNumber);` is causing the issue. Before getting element at `indexNumber` make sure if list is not empty.

Comment: I added the stack with the errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArrayList index out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729786/arraylist-index-out-of-bounds)

Answer (score 0):

**Why it Fails:**

A specific sequence of events that leads to the out of bounds exception would be, for example:

```
minChange(1, [4]) // goes into second-to-last (else if) case, since 4 > 1. 4 is then removed.
minChange(1, [])  // crashes
```

It's not clear what your code was intended to do in this case, since your pseudo-code doesn't define `minChange(a, ds)`.

Even if we stipulate that the input list has to have more than one item, we'll often hit this same case:

```
minChange(5,[4, 8])
minChange(1,[8])
minChange(1,[])
```

I'm not sure what you intended to happen here, but, anyway, there are other issues...

**Bugs:**

There is very likely a bug in your code with this line:

```
// this just creates another reference to the existing list
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536094/java-arraylist-copy
// meaning: both recursive calls will operate on the same list
// even though one uses the "updatedList" reference and one uses "integerList"
List<Integer> updatedList = integerList;
```

Also, the use of `indexNumber` indicates a bug, since it's only ever used when it has value 0 - the incrementing is pointless. Remember that local variables in the function are getting 'reset' in each recursive call, unless you pass them as a parameter.

**Debugging Strategies:**

First, clarify what you actually want the algorithm to do.

Then, check what it's actually doing. As a debugging technique, I would recommend adding some print statement at the start of the function call:

```
System.out.println("minChange(" + a + ", " + integerList + ")");
```

...so that you can see a log of what happened before the crash. You can also use a debugger for this purpose.

Finally, once it works on some simple cases, write a fuzz tester that checks your algorithm on a bunch of random lists and `a`s of different sizes, to see if there are any cases that you missed.